# JSON file not found

Tags: node.js, strapi

I have a json file with the name of email_templates.json placed in the same folder as my js file bootstrap.js. when I try to read the file I get an error.

```
no such file or directory, open './email_templates.json'
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
"use strict";
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = async () => {
const { config } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./email_templates.json'));
  console.log(config);
};
```

**email_templates.json**

```
[
    {
        "name":"vla",
        "subject":"test template",
        "path": ""
    }
]
```

I am using VS code , for some reason VS code doesnt autocomplete the path as well which is confusing for me.Does anyone know why it is doing this?
Node v:14*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to get the full path (right from `C:\`, for example, if you are on Windows).

---

To do this, you first need to import `path` in your code.

```js
const path = require("path");
```

Next, we need to join the directory in which the JavaScript file is in and the JSON filename. To do this, we will use the code below.

```js
const jsonPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "email_templates.json");
```

The `resolve()` function basically mixes the two paths together to make one complete, valid path.

Finally, you can use this path to pass into `readFileSync()`.

```js
fs.readFileSync(jsonPath);
```

This should help with finding the path, if the issue was that it didn't like the relative path. The absolute path may help it find the file.

---

In conclusion, this solution should help with finding the path.

Comment: I didnt know it was that complicated the jsonPath solution worked for me.

Comment: That's great! I'll remove the other solution.

Comment: How will this work on live server